# Sometimes hitting 'undo' changes position of view (moves view quickly to top of the code)

Tags: java, eclipse, undo-redo

When typing code, *sometimes* when doing 'undo' (via Ctrl+Z), the program automatically scrolls all the way up in that code to the very top, and then I gotta either scroll back down to where my cursor is, or I gotta type something and it will automatically scroll down to where my cursor is. And then I don't know what was actually undone in these cases, because it quickly scrolls right up to the top right when I 'undo', so I can't see what changed.

It's annoying. Does anyone know of a fix to just keep the camera view unchanged when hitting 'undo'?

What I've tried:
Not much, I can't find anywhere in preferences how to disable this affect when hitting 'undo' via Ctrl+Z, can't find anything to do with 'undo' except in keyboard shortcuts or anything to do with moving the view to the top of the code.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the latest Eclipse version. Try it with a fresh Eclipse installation and fresh workspace without additional installed plugins (probably it is caused by a plugin you have installed). _"Does this happen to anyone else?"_ is not a smart question and [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You probably made some code edit that caused the editor to add or remove an import statement in the list of imports at the top of the file. The import change is considered a separate change from the code change which caused the import change.

You're probably aware that when you undo or redo a change, the editor view jumps to show the part of the code that was changed. When you undo the import change, the view will naturally shift to the top of the file, where the import statements are.

I wasn't able to find any eclipse preferences to affect this behavior.